# Skipping iterations in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried to skip some iterations in a for loop:

```
Lines <- "
 time   Temperature
  1         38.3
  2         38.5
  3         38.9
  4         40.1
  5         38.0
  6         38.6
  7         37.9
  8         38.2
  9         37.5
  10        38.0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

for (i in unique(DF$time)){
 ix=which(i==DF$time)
 if(DF$Temperature[ix] > 38.65)  ix=ix+3
 print(ix)
}
```

But I don't get the desired output. It is not skipping the iterations. Instead it just overwrites it so that I get some iterations twice.

Output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Desired output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

**Update:**

```
i=1
while(i<=DF$time){
  if(DF$Temperature[i] > 38.65){  
    print(i)
    i=i+3}
    i=i+1
}
```

That is what I tried. But obviously its wrong. Never used while before. Can someone help me?

Comment: `which` returns a vector of all matching values, not just the first one.  You perhaps need `ix=which(i==DF$time)[1]`.

Comment: I dont understand your desired output. Indexed from 6 to 10 are all below your temperature threshold. You want your indexes to restart from the previous one, after the changing?

Comment: you could achieve your desired output with `which(!DF$Temperature > 38.65)`. Not sure if this is an artifact of the example, or if you are just trying to get the indices where temperature does not exceed a threshold, in which case the for loop is not necessary.

Comment: @AndrewGustar That wouldn't be an issue in this example since `DF$time == 1:10`. I think the issue is that OP thinks of R for loops as working how for loops work in, e.g., C++, while they actually work much more like foreach loops in C++ (see, e.g., [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-April/159353.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40-foreach-in-c-and-java/))

Comment: Why would it skip iterations?  You keep resetting the variable `ix` to `i` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Eventually you want to change `i` (or something like *go ahead three steps* in `DF$time`) after `ix = ix+3`. This is not possible in your construct because you are iterating over `DF$time`. But even if you would iterating over an index for `DF$time` it is impossible: `for (i in 1:10) { print(i); if (i==3) i <- i+3 }` In `R` it is impossible to manipulate the running index from in the for-loop (I know, some other programming languages can do that). You have to take a more general loop (i.e. **repeat** or **while**)

Comment: your for loop is set up to iterate through each item in `DF$time`, so it will not skip any of these iterations unless you redefine it to only loop through the items in `DF$time` that you want.

Comment: @DavidKlotz Exactly -- it does *not* work like a for loop in some other languages

Comment: ok I see its a bad example. I make it more clearly.

Comment: Ok so there is my mistake. But I tried it with while as well but there is a mistake too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing `for` vs. `while` clauses in R.  This does basically what you're trying to do:

```
ix <- 1
while(ix <= 10) {
  if (DF$Temperature[ix] > 38.65) {
    ix = ix + 3
    print(ix)
  } else{
    print(ix)

  }
  ix = ix + 1
}
```

*edited with @jogo's correction*

Comment: I already thought while is the better option. But with this code is the 6. iteration repeated.

Comment: Thanks @jogo, I put that up a little too quickly

Answer (score 0):

As per your input, only the 3rd and 4th index has the  DF$Temperature > 38.65 comparison giving tru result, rest is false.

The R comparison 38.6 > 38.65  will give a result equal to false.

So,

```
   DF$Temperature > 38.65
   [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So your output is according to the logic here, the 3rd and 4th index is incremented by 3.

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6 # index3 +3
[1] 7 # index 4 +3
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```